# Sun is not casting shadows

Tags: light, eevee-render-engine, shadows, glass

I am at the very beginning of my blender journey, so dont judge me xD
i have tried this very basic model of a apartment like room.
I am using eevee and i have 2 questions.
First im wondering why my sun is not casting any shadows. It had before but now it doesn't anymore. Shadows are on.
Second how do i change my glass material so the sun can shine through it.
but even if i delete the window the shadows are not coming back :/.
Thank you for your help already <3

[image]

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=6427" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/6427/)

Comment: This is due to two aspects: your scene elements are large and the sun is far: change the shadow 'clip end' value of the sun to 300m. Secondly, the glasses are opaque: change their shadow mode to 'None' (don't think other shadow mode can work here)

Comment: First tank you for your quick response. changing the clip end does not work for me but downscaling the whole scene did. but now i cant zoom in far enough to work with how do you manage this problem? Also you cant see my glasses from outside anymore

Comment: Have not reopened the file, but if I remember well you'll need to set the glass material to alpha blend (it was opaque).

Comment: Hm i did that. It doesnt solve the problem unfortunatly. Also you can see through the windows from outside but youre not able to see the outside from inside. My camera will be placed inside so i need to fix that xD Any ideas? 'This is the updated file [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=6444" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/6444/)

Comment: Have added the blend file in the answer below. Don't know why yet yours does not work.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Obtained with:

- For the sun:

Shadow clip end set to 300m.

[image]

- For the glass:

Blend mode to alpha blend.

Shadow mode to none (or alpha clip, but with a threshold of 1... so).

[image]

[image]